# sharepoint App Model: Not able to fetch the app part's custom properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have a provider hosted app for which I have created a clientwebpart item. In this clientWebPart I have added some custom properties:

```
<Content Type="html" Src="~remoteAppUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?strProp=_strProp_" />
<Properties>
  <Property
           Name="strProp"
           Type="string"
           RequiresDesignerPermission="true"
           DefaultValue="String default value"
           WebCategory="Basic app part category"
           WebDisplayName="A property of type string.">
  </Property>
</Properties>
```

But the problem is that on code behind file when I does below operation in page_Load() I always got **NULL**. Even thou I have remove {StandardToken} I am still getting the values of those

```
 string s = Request.QueryString["strProp"]; //always give null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved by making a separate page for client app part. When we create a new client app part page and create new query string there, then SharePoint appends those specified query to the client app part page and not on the start page of App.